# Suppress ORCID author footnote in els-cas-templates document class

Tags: footnotes, author, els-cas

I’m using the `els-cas-templates` [LaTeX package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/) ([doc](https://support.stmdocs.in/wiki/index.php?title=Elsarticle_-_CAS)). I will be submitting to an Elsevier journal, [which allows this official package for submission](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions). I have not touched any of the template files. I am editing/building on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com).

I have not provided any ORCIDs for the authors, however there is still a blank ORCID footnote being displayed. How do I suppress that without modifying the template? I have emailed the package authors, but have yet to receive a reply.

Here is my LaTeX author code:

```
\author[1]{John Smith}
\cormark[1]
\ead{jsmith@example.com}
\author[2]{John Doe}
```

The title page footnotes look like this:
[image]

But they should look like this (format)(copied from published article):
[image]

Also there is an email img instead of the word "*E-mail address*". I can ask that as a separate question if requested.

Comment: Notice, however, that some journals require ORCIDs, some even for _all_ authors. I mean, there might be a reason for the template to do what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}   
\renewcommand{\printorcid}{}  % this will make this function do nothing.
\ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This does involve making a small edit in the template. As a work-around it worked when I commented out the line with `\printorcid` in the .sty file.

Comment: I've been waiting for other suggestions, hoping that I could overwrite the behavior with a redefinition in the main file without touching the template/preamble. If I don't get any, I will accept this answer. Thank you.