# els-cas-templates no highlighting of author names

Tags: elsarticle, author, els-cas

I've been using the [els-cas-templates](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/) LaTeX package by Elsevier. I will be submitting to an Elsevier journal, [which allows this official package for submission](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions). I have not touched any of the template files, nor do I want to. I am editing/building on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/project). I am using the [cas-dc](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates/cas-dc-template.pdf) (double column) format, because it most resembles the journal I am submitting to.

I have looked at the [documentation](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates/doc/elsdoc-cas.pdf), and I can't figure out how to turn off highlighting of author names. Is it possible? The journal I am submitting to (Solar Energy) **DOES NOT have highlighted author names**.

Although I don't think providing the following example file code is actually useful (as the CTAN template clearly has a file that does this), I am providing this code as example of a "stripped down" main `tex` file that includes their `cas-dc.cls` file because it was requested in the comments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}

\begin{document}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}

\shorttitle{Short title}
\shortauthors{J. Smith et~al.}

\title [mode = title]{Here is a title}                      

\author[1]{John Smith}
\cormark[1]
\ead{some@email.com}
\author[2]{John Doe}
\address[1]{School A}
\address[2]{School B}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author.}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
some \sep keywords \sep here
\end{keywords}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-10]

\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

[I also have another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499683/134042) about this template (ORCIDs), that I'd like to fix without touching the template code, if possible. I am not getting any official support from the package authors, having emailed them. **I would rather not change their template for submission.**

Comment: If you are submitting to an Elsevier journal using their class, then you are probably not allowed to change the appearance of elements like the title. If you still change it then it will probably be changed back by the Elsevier editing department during the publication process. As Elsevier states on the page you linked: "Use the standard layout or keep layout changes to a minimum. (Custom layout will be removed.)".

Comment: But if you still want to change it then please provide a small compilable document in your question that produces an article with one or two authors and no content, so we have a starting point to answer the question. You can add code to your question by using the `edit` button below the post.

Comment: You misunderstand. The journal (Solar Energy) does not have highlighting in the names. However, this template, which is allow for submission, DOES. I want it off, to match the journal.

Comment: There is no point is sending you code. You can download the package yourself, and by default it highlights author names. The Elsevier journal I am submitting to, does not, yet supports this template... So if you can figure out how to get around that, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: ok, in that case it may be useful to change the highlighting. Still, if you can provide a small example document in your question that would save potential answerers time in creating such an example itself.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. There is no minimal set of code to copy for this question. There is nothing I've changed from the default build. Download it from CTAN and try it yourself. Then try to take it off. It's pretty simple, buddy.

Comment: Then you should copy the default build into your question, preferably minimized (there are most likely many elements in the example article in the download that are not important for your question). And please don't say things like "it's pretty simple, buddy", that does not build any goodwill from the volunteers here that may be interested in answering your question.

Comment: Look, @Marijn, I'm not trying to get in a flame war with you, but I've used Stack Overflow for 6 years. And I DO put code in when it's relavant. This case clearly isn't. And I don't like users like yourself that ignore logic in lieu of providing noobie support. Don't tell me to put code in from an entire template that can be downloaded, and which will be MUCH more accurate that getting it from another user on the site. The template is several files. There is no way I could copy all of it, and copying parts  of it is even worse. So please, if you want to help, download the template from CTAN.

Comment: I also answer questions. And given this question, I would download the template and build it in 3 seconds. Then try to figure it out.

Comment: As provided in my original question, here is the link on CTAN to the package. Building any of the formats (cas-dc, cas-sc) will result in a file that has highlighted author names: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates.zip

Comment: I appreciate any actual support you can provide in disabling the highlighting. Personally, I suspect the package authors didn't provide a way to do that...

Comment: It's ok to download a template to answer the question, especially when it is on CTAN, which means many people will have it anyway. However, it would improve the question if you provide a small document that _uses_ the template, just a few lines that is a stripped-down version of `cas-dc-template.tex` that produces a minimal article with only auhtor names. That file loads `cas-dc.cls`, of course it is fine when the contents of that file is not included in the question.

Comment: I did not do this because the template comes with a file that does exactly that. I've attempted to contact Elsevier again through author support on their website. They say they'll get back to me in email. We'll see what happens. I suspect the template has multiple issues that don't allow me to align it exactly to Solar Energy, even though it's the closes Elsevier template I can find. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Provided stripped down version of thier `cas-dc-template.tex` in case anyone needs that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution is to explicitly set the author names in black.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,draft]{cas-dc}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}

\begin{document}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}

\shorttitle{Short title}
\shortauthors{J. Smith et~al.}

\title [mode = title]{Here is a title}                      

\author[1]{\color{black}John Smith}
\cormark[1]
\ead{some@email.com}
\author[2]{\color{black}John Doe}
\address[1]{School A}
\address[2]{School B}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author.}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
some \sep keywords \sep here
\end{keywords}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

A more involved solution (but conceptually maybe better) is to redefine the `\author` macro from within the main document. Unfortunately the macro is rather long, so this takes space in the document (I tried an `xpatch` solution but I could not make that work). The author first names are printed with color `\l_stm_augroup_color_tl !50`, so 50% of the default black (rendering as gray). Changing this to just `\l_stm_augroup_color_tl` renders the first names as black.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,draft]{cas-dc}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \author { O{} m O{} }
   {
     \ResetMarks
     \tl_if_blank:nTF { #3 } { }
       { \keys_set:nn { stm / author } { #3 } }
%
     \int_gincr:N \g_stm_au_int  
     \tex_gdef:D \theau@ { \int_use:N \g_stm_au_int }
%
     \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_stm_prelimsau_seq { #2 }
     \bool_if:NTF \l_stm_au_collab_bool
       { \seq_gput_right:cn { g_stm_clau\int_use:N \g_stm_augr_int _seq } }
       { \seq_gput_right:cn { g_stm_au\int_use:N \g_stm_augr_int _seq } }
       {          
         \int_gincr:N \g_stm_aau_int  
         \tex_gdef:D \theauthor {\int_use:N \g_stm_aau_int }
         \keys_set:nn { stm /author } { #3 }
         \tl_if_head_eq_catcode:nNTF { #1 } a
            { \processAffRef { #1 } }
            { \processAffNum { #1 } }
         \tl_if_empty:NF \l_stm_au_prefix
            { \l_stm_au_prefix_tl \c_space_token } 
         \str_if_eq:VnTF \l_stm_au_style_tl  { chinese }
            { %\msg_term:n {STYLE~T=\l_stm_au_style_tl........}
              \invparsename { #2 } 
              \textcolor{\l_stm_augroup_color_tl}{\surname}
              \no_break_space:
              \textcolor{\l_stm_augroup_color_tl}{\firstname}  %%% CHANGE HERE
            }
            { %\msg_term:n {STYLE~F=\l_stm_au_style_tl........}  
              \parsename { #2 } 
              \textcolor{\l_stm_augroup_color_tl}{\firstname} %%% AND HERE
              \no_break_space:
              \textcolor{\l_stm_augroup_color_tl}{\surname}
            }
        \tl_if_empty:NF \l_stm_au_suffix_tl
        { \c_space_token \l_stm_au_suffix_tl }
         \unskip
         \textsuperscript
         {
           \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 }
           { \tex_def:D \sep{} }
           { {\itshape\listAff} \tex_def:D \sep{\unskip,} }
           \process@marks 
           \bool_if:NT \l_stm_au_deceased_bool 
           { \sep \maltese
             \tex_def:D \sep { \unksip, }
           }
         }
        \tl_if_empty:NF \l_stm_au_degree_tl
        { ,\c_space_token \l_stm_au_degree_tl }
        \tl_if_empty:NF \l_stm_au_role_tl
        { \c_space_token (\l_stm_au_role_tl) }
%
       \ResetMarks
      }
%
      \bool_if:NT \l_stm_au_deceased_bool 
       { 
        \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_stm_maltese_seq
         {
          \tex_def:D \thefootnote { \maltese }
          \footnotetext{Deceased~author.} 
         } 
       }
% various social media
      \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_stm_au_facebook_tl { }
        { 
          \wrAux { \token_to_str:N \facebookauthor
            { \l_stm_au_facebook_tl } { \exp_not:n {#2} } }
        }
      \tl_if_empty:NF \l_stm_au_twitter_tl
        { 
          \wrAux { \token_to_str:N \twitterauthor
            { \l_stm_au_twitter_tl } { \exp_not:n {#2} } }
        }
      \tl_if_empty:NF \l_stm_au_gplus_tl
        { 
          \wrAux { \token_to_str:N \gplusauthor
            { \l_stm_au_gplus_tl } { \exp_not:n {#2} } }
        }
      \tl_if_empty:NF \l_stm_au_linkedin_tl
        { 
          \wrAux { \token_to_str:N \linkedinauthor
            { \l_stm_au_linkedin_tl } { \exp_not:n {#2} } }
        }
      \tl_if_empty:NF \l_stm_au_orcid_tl
        { 
          \wrAux { \token_to_str:N \orcidauthor
            { \l_stm_au_orcid_tl } { \exp_not:n {#2} } }
        }
%
        \@eadauthor={#2}
        \pdfstringdef\__info_au: { #2 }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \theau@ } < { 4 }
        { \xappto \infoauthors { \__info_au: , ~ } }
        {
          \int_compare:nNnTF { \theau@ } = { 4 }
          { \xappto \infoauthors { et~al. } }
          { }
        }        
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}

\begin{document}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}

\shorttitle{Short title}
\shortauthors{J. Smith et~al.}

\title [mode = title]{Here is a title}                      

\author[1]{John Smith}
\cormark[1]
\ead{some@email.com}
\author[2]{John Doe}
\address[1]{School A}
\address[2]{School B}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author.}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
some \sep keywords \sep here
\end{keywords}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I rarely color text, so I didn't even think of that.

Comment: As for the style file edit option, if I changed the `\l_stm_augroup_color_tl` line, do you think that they would automatically reject my submission? Meaning, do you think Elsevier has a script that compares their template `.cls` files and if it finds any edits, it rejects outright? I would be ok with making this simple change, only if you think they don't have that process. As for myself, I have no idea. It's hard to believe they would... but then people get very up-in-arms about changing style files, so I don't know.

Comment: @delrocco the idea is to change the definition of `\author` not in the style file (which would be rejected) but from your own `.tex` file (which may be allowed), as demonstrated in the MWE here.

Comment: Ok, right, I saw you provided the redefinition. But then I thought you might be suggesting that I could change that one line from the style file if desired. So your recommendation is to not touch the style file at all. Only redefine. Thank you.